# Google Analytics with wildcard domains + subdomains

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics

I want to have a single script in my shell/layout page that provides insight on whatever url is currently being used.  I have a multitenant app that has URLs like:

- app1.myapp.com
- custom.com
- myapp.com

These all are different domains, but will be hitting the same application with the same page.  How can I use google analytics to report from "whatever the active URL is", instead of specifying URLs in the `<script>`?  I'm trying to avoid specifying domains because users of the app can map their own domains, so manual mapping will be unwieldy.

I have the following:

```
<script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'SSSSSSSSS', 'mysite.com'); // something here?  I've tried document.URL
        ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

But this only tracks requests made to the base domain (myapp.com, sub.myapp.com), not other domains (differentapp.com).  What changes do I need to make to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document.url would not work because the expected format for this parameter (cookie domain) is a domain name, not a full url. But you can set the parameter to "auto" (or not set it all).

Comment: It's nice to know why this doesn't work, but it doesn't give any insight into the question asked.  Do you have any pointers there?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - don't use a specific domain name as parameter to the "create" call but use "auto" (so Google will pick the current hostname as cookie domain automatically).

Comment: I cannot believe that it was that simple.  I owe you beer.